# Need help in optimising clojure statement

Tags: clojure, riemann

I'm very new to clojure and need to set up a [riemann](http://riemann.io) config so that it would be easy to edit/add new conditions. What we have now:

```
(defn tell-ops 
([to]
    (by [:service]
        (throttle 3 360
            (rollup 2 360
                slackerDefault
                (email to)))))
([to channel]
    (by [:service]
        (throttle 3 360
            (rollup 2 360
                (slacker channel)
                (email to))))))

    ............

(where (state "FATAL")
    (where (service #"^Serv1")
            (tell-ops "dev.ops1@foo.com" "#dev-ops1"))

    (where (service #"^Serv2")
            (tell-ops "dev.ops2@bar.com"))
   ....

)
```

moreover, it lacks the default statement, something like 
    if nothing matches, tell-ops "admin@fo.bar"

I think I need something like a top level struct

```
(def services 
 [{:regex #"^serv1" :mail "foo@bar.com" :channel "#serv1"} 
  {:regex #"serv2$" :mail "foo@baz.com"} ])
```

so that it would be easy to add new ones. But I have no idea how to loop throuth this array considering absence of :channel in the second case and making a "default call" if none of the regexes matches

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Riemann, but I think you can solve your problem using standard Clojure data processing tools. I like your idea of a top-level structure for the alert policies. I would add a catch-all policy at the end to handle the default case. Modifying your code a bit to make it less Riemann-specific:

```
(defn tell-ops!
  [{:keys [mail channel]}]
  (when mail (println (str "mail = " mail)))
  (when channel (println (str "channel = " channel))))

(def policies
  [{:regex #"^serv1.*" :mail "foo@bar.com" :channel "#serv1"}
   {:regex #".*serv2$" :mail "foo@baz.com"} 
   {:regex #".*" :mail "default@bar.com"}])

(defn alert!
  [policies service-in-alert]
  (-> (drop-while (fn 
                    [{:keys [regex]}] 
                    (nil? (re-matches regex service-in-alert))) 
        policies)
    first
    tell-ops!))
```

Some notes:

- it's idiomatic to use `!` in function names for functions that produce side effects (such as posting a message to a channel or sending an e-mail)
- if you want a hard default for the `tell-ops!`function, you can use Clojure's support for default values when destructuring maps: `{:keys [mail channel] :or {mail "default@foo.bar" channel "#default-chan"}}`

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and post the results here!